# adding custom options to Super+Middle Mouse context menu

Tags: mouse, context-menu, productivity

I'm using Ubuntu 22.10. When I do Super + click the middle mouse button I get a context menu that lists a bunch of useful stuff.

[image]

Let's say I want to add some stuff there. How would I do that, like a custom script or command? Maybe add a submenu with a list of snippets. I think it would be extremely useful, but I have no idea how to go about this and where this would be defined. Do you have any clever ideas?

Comment: xdotool should let you run a script on mouse events. then look for a  tool to do a popup to select scripts  from that.   https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=linux+popup+menu+run+scripts&ia=web

alternative us custom keyboard to trigger same.  I am not sure if xdotool would overwrite the default mouse function in Ubuntu or programs.

Comment: @pierrely xdotool won´t work on Wayland. You cannot add to this menu without editing source code. For snippets, there is a dedicated tool "espanso", or you can do some scripting. These are triggered through the keyboard, though (which certainly makes sense for snippets).

Comment: echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE  gets me wayland (lower case w) . xdotools getactivewindow returns a result.